# Cannot manage to install jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, jestjs, npm-install

I am using `npm` to install `jest` in order to perform some tests over my js code.
In order to install it I use the command:

```
$ npm install --save-dev jest
```

As described on their website.

However, it fails over and over again with these errors:
[image]

What should I do in order to install `jest` properly?

This is my package.json :

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "jest": "^23.5.0",
    "react-scripts": "0.6.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "adal-angular": "^1.0.13",
    "axios": "^0.15.3",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "lodash": "^4.16.4",
    "react": "^15.4.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.30.5",
    "react-bootstrap-typeahead": "^1.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.2",
    "react-http-request": "^1.0.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "description": "This project was bootstrapped with [Create React App] 
  (https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app).",
  "main": "index.js",
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Current message:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fwji1.png)

Comment: doesn't look like anything to do with jest or react, I'd try `rn -rf node_modules` (or Win equivalent) and maybe clear npm cache `npm cache clean --force` and try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please install react v16 for this:

```
npm install --save react@^16.4.2 react-dom@^16.4.2
```

then run this command:

```
npm update --save
```

to get all dependent packages

Comment: please share your `package.json`

Comment: it says react is v15

Comment: I surely installed v16.. Should I change it manually or is there any other way to update it ?

Comment: I did it again now just to ensure and got the message above (edited my question again)

Comment: I didn't see any changes in your post

Comment: Still don't see ? There is a link attached

Comment: Yes, and then ran  install --save-dev jest again and got the message above.see the "current message" link

Comment: Hi, now my package.json shows again react v.15 (as above). when I go over your steps above it wouldn't change...

Comment: Write “rm -rf node_modules” and then update version of react and react dom to latest then npm install again

Comment: Did it.. still no change in package.json :\

Comment: Change your directory and update the version and then npm install otherwise there's something else wrong. It has nothing to do with package.json, You can post a new question and then users would be able to see the problem and might give the solution of problem

Comment: The order of what I write exactly to console is: rm -rf node_modules, then npm update react then, npm update reactdom and finally npm install . Is that right?

Comment: no, rm -rf node_modules then npm install but update react and react-dom version before

Comment: can you please try to help me with another issue? I asked a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52291444/typeerror-cannot-read-property-bool-of-undefined Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I simply deleted the node_modules and package-lock.json, and use yarn to re-install everything. And it worked...