# TypeError: Cannot read property 'bool' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typeerror, jestjs

```
 FAIL  src/App.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

TypeError: Cannot read property 'bool' of undefined

  2 | import logo from './logo.svg';
  3 | import './App.css';
> 4 | import { Grid, Row, Col, Table, Panel, Image, Tabs, Tab, Nav, NavItem, Alert} from 'react-bootstrap';
    | ^
  5 | import _ from 'lodash';
  6 | import $ from 'jquery';
  7 | import Request from 'react-http-request';

  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-bootstrap/node_modules/react-overlays/lib/Transition.js:259:33)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-bootstrap/lib/Collapse.js:41:19)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-bootstrap/lib/index.js:62:18)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/App.js:4:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/App.test.js:4:1)
```

I get this error everytime I run npm test.

All I want is to make App.test.js work.

I have updated all my dependencies to the latest (besides 'axios', 'react-bootstrap', 'react-bootstrap-tpeahead', 'bootstrap', 'react-scripts', which I couldn't).

I also have been told that from React v15 and up (I use 16.5.0) I have to import PropTypes from 'prop-types' and not from 'React'. However, I added the line

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
```

to every single component and to App.js, still does not work.

I also got a suggestion:

"Seems to be an error in react-boostrap itself. Check the line in Transition.js where the error appears. I'll bet it tries to access a property on window. But window won't exist in the test context - it's just a console application running in node after all".

I have no idea what it means but I do have a problem with Transition.js for sure (as the error that I get shows)

How can I make this test work? I have read many solutions but non helped me...

Package.json :

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "^23.6.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "enzyme": "^3.6.0",
    "jest": "^23.6.0",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^15.6.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.5.0",
    "react-scripts": "^0.6.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.5.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "adal-angular": "^1.0.17",
    "axios": "^0.15.3",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.10",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
    "react": "^16.5.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.30.10",
    "react-bootstrap-typeahead": "^1.4.2",
    "react-http-request": "^1.0.4",
    "react-overlays": "^0.8.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
     "test": "jest",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "description": "This project was bootstrapped with [Create React App (https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app).",
  "main": "index.js",
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "jest": {
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js",
      "\\.(css|less)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/styleMock.js"
    },
    "transform": {
      "\\.js$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest"
      }
}
```

.babelrc

```
{
 "presets": ["env", "react"]
}
```

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import { Grid, Row, Col, Table, Panel, Image, Tabs, Tab, Nav, NavItem, Alert} from 'react-bootstrap';
import _ from 'lodash';
import $ from 'jquery';
import Request from 'react-http-request';
import {AdminViewComponent} from './components/AdminViewComponent.js';
import {WholeScreen} from './components/WholeScreenComponent.js';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';



class App extends Component {


  render() {

    var url = "./api/user/" + this.props.userName + "/";
    console.log("props = " + JSON.stringify(this.props));
    console.log("url = " + url);
    var userCompanyIcon;
    //if (this.props.tid == "49d3d3cf-cde6-4161-8d6d-1789042d7b01"){
    if (this.props.tid == "72f988bf-86f1-41af-91ab-2d7cd011db47" || this.props.tid == "49d3d3cf-cde6-4161-8d6d-1789042d7b01"){
      userCompanyIcon = <Image className="userCompanyIcon" src="microsoft-gray.png" responsive/>;
    }


    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="App-header">
          <Grid>
          <Row>
          <Col xs={6} sm={6} md={6}>                       

          </Col>
          <Col xs={2} sm={2} md={2}>

          </Col>
          <Col xs={4} sm={4} md={4}>

            <div className="Hello">Hello, {this.props.fisrtName} </div>                       
          </Col>

          </Row>
          <Row>
            <Col xs={4}  sm={4}  md={4}  >
              {userCompanyIcon}
            </Col>
            <Col xs={4}  sm={4}  md={4}  >

            </Col>
            <Col xs={4} sm={4} md={4}>                       
              <Image className="companyIcon" src="MatanTransperent.png" responsive />              
            </Col>
          </Row>
      </Grid>                    
    </div>   


    <div className="App-content">

     <Request
      url= {url}
      method='get'
      accept='application/json'
      headers={{'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.props.token}}
      verbose={true}>
      {
          ({error, result, loading}) => {
            if (loading) {
              return <div>loading...</div>;
            } else {
              if (result == null || result.statusType == 4 ||result.statusType == 5){
                return <div> an unknown error has occured.  </div>;
              }
              else{
                var returnObject = JSON.parse(result.text);
                if (returnObject.isAdmin == false){
                  return <WholeScreen data={returnObject.DonationsList}/>;
                }
                else if (returnObject.isAdmin == true){
                  return <AdminViewComponent token={this.props.token} />;

                }
              }
            }
          }
        } 
      </Request>-
    </div>
  </div>
);
  }
}

export default App;
```

The test code:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'; 
import {shallow} from 'enzyme';
import CheckboxWithLabel from '../CheckboxWithLabel';
test('CheckboxWithLabel changes the text after click', () => {
  const checkbox = shallow(
    <CheckboxWithLabel labelOn="On" labelOff="Off" />
  );
  expect(checkbox.text()).toEqual('Off');
  checkbox.find('input').simulate('change');
  expect(checkbox.text()).toEqual('On');
});
```

Comment: where is your test written ?

Comment: Hi! it's in the src folder

Comment: Share your written test code

Comment: Added to the question, it's the initial App.test.js, as far as I know it should work - I didn't touch anything there besides adding imports

Comment: This isn't how you test, you need to either shallow or mount render this component

Comment: I know, but this is the initial App.test.js I know it works to everyone just as is, anyway, I edited my question again so you can see another test which does not work

Comment: I have added an answer this will probably fix your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transform your modules for ES6 feature in test environment. Just add this code to your Jest config:

```
 "transform": {
  "\\.js$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest"
},
```

Comment: Can you please see my package.json? I added it, just want to make sure it's the way you meant

Comment: Great, I did it, but unfortunately seems to still not pass the test :/

Comment: It shouldn't throw "import" error now. You can post the error a new question so you more users will be able to see the problem. You current problem is solved anyways

Comment: Hi I posted the error in a new question, will appreciate if you could take a look.

Comment: Here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52311210/testing-components-with-jest-fails/52311274#52311274