# testing fails with Jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, azure, unit-testing, jestjs

I have got a code for which I have to perform tests on. After installing Jest and using it with enzyme for testing different components, now I have to check that only Authorized tenants can access my website. Both client side and server side are built on Azure.

All I want to do is to test that a known tenant (See App.js) will be authorized.

For this tenants testing, I should use the App.js.

I cannot figure out for what reason my test fails ?

App.test.js :

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import { shallow, configure } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

it('renders without crashing', () => {
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    ReactDOM.render(<App />, div);
});

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

const tid = "72f988bf-86f1-41af-91ab-2d7cd011db47";
it('Authorizes a known tenant', () => {
const app = shallow(<App tid={tid} />);
const el = app.find('[src=microsoft-gray.png]');
expect(el.exists()).to.equal(true);

});
```

The error:

```
  ● Authorizes a known tenant


TypeError: Cannot read property 'equal' of undefined

  16 |     const app = shallow(<App tid={tid} />);
  17 |     const el = app.find('[src="microsoft-gray.png"]');
> 18 |     expect(el.exists()).to.equal(true);
     |     ^
  19 | });
```

App.js :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import './App.css';
import { Grid, Row, Col, Table, Panel, Image, Tabs, Tab, Nav, NavItem, Alert } from 'react-bootstrap';
import _ from 'lodash';
import $ from 'jquery';
import Request from 'react-http-request';
import { AdminViewComponent } from './components/AdminViewComponent.js';
import { WholeScreen } from './components/WholeScreenComponent.js';
import logo from './logo.svg';

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        var url = "./api/user/" + this.props.userName + "/";
        console.log("props = " + JSON.stringify(this.props));
        console.log("url = " + url);
        var userCompanyIcon;
        //if (this.props.tid == "49d3d3cf-cde6-4161-8d6d-1789042d7b01"){
        if (this.props.tid == "72f988bf-86f1-41af-91ab-2d7cd011db47" || this.props.tid == "49d3d3cf-cde6-4161-8d6d-1789042d7b01") {
            userCompanyIcon = <Image className="userCompanyIcon" src="microsoft-gray.png" responsive />;
        }

        return (
            <div className="App">
                <div className="App-header">
                    <Grid>
                        <Row>
                            <Col xs={6} sm={6} md={6}>

                            </Col>
                            <Col xs={2} sm={2} md={2}>

                            </Col>
                            <Col xs={4} sm={4} md={4}>

                                <div className="Hello">Hello, {this.props.fisrtName} </div>
                            </Col>

                        </Row>
                        <Row>
                            <Col xs={4} sm={4} md={4}  >
                                {userCompanyIcon}
                            </Col>
                            <Col xs={4} sm={4} md={4}  >

                            </Col>
                            <Col xs={4} sm={4} md={4}>
                                <Image className="companyIcon" src="MatanTransperent.png" responsive />
                            </Col>
                        </Row>
                    </Grid>
                </div>


                <div className="App-content">

                    <Request
                        url={url}
                        method='get'
                        accept='application/json'
                        headers={{ 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.props.token }}
                        verbose={true}>
                        {
                            ({ error, result, loading }) => {
                                if (loading) {
                                    return <div>Loading...</div>;
                                } else {
                                    if (result == null || result.statusType == 4 || result.statusType == 5) {
                                        return <div> An unknown error has occured. Please try again.  </div>;
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        var returnObject = JSON.parse(result.text);
                                        if (returnObject.isAdmin == false) {
                                            return <WholeScreen data={returnObject.DonationsList} />;
                                        }
                                        else if (returnObject.isAdmin == true) {
                                            return <AdminViewComponent token={this.props.token} />;

                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    </Request>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: try with quotes: `app.find('[src="microsoft-gray.png"]')`

Comment: Worked! But there's another issue, edited my question again.

Comment: sorry I think I used the wrong syntax, toEqual is what it should be for Jest, Changed my answer

Comment: Yes I just tried toEqual a second ago, but still didn't work

Comment: Ok! It passes now! May I use your knowledge for another subject ?

Comment: Glad it works! We should not clutter the thread too much if it's not related the current question. Perhaps better to open a new one instead.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180411/discussion-between-etarhan-and-i-zvi).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are searching on ID #tid, and it seems like you don't have any elements that have an ID of #tid. You are passing tid as an property and aren't using it afterwards, aside from you conditionally rendering logic.

You also have other options than using CSS selectors to find your element ([see here](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/find.html)). If your goal is actually to see if the image renders you could try app.find('.userCompanyIcon');`or app.find('[src="microsoft-gray.png"]');`

If you were actually checking whether your property is set then `app.prop('tid')` would also give you the tenant id.

So either:

```
const tid = "72f988bf-86f1-41af-91ab-2d7cd011db47";
it('Authorizes a known tenant', () => {
    const app = shallow(<App tid={tid} />);
    const el = app.find('.userCompanyIcon');
    expect(el.exists()).toEqual(true);

});
```

Or:

```
const tid = "72f988bf-86f1-41af-91ab-2d7cd011db47";
it('Authorizes a known tenant', () => {
    const app = shallow(<App tid={tid} />);
    const el = app.find('[src="microsoft-gray.png"]');
    expect(el.exists()).toEqual(true);

});
```

Or the below, but this doesn't test much:

```
const tid = "72f988bf-86f1-41af-91ab-2d7cd011db47";
it('Authorizes a known tenant', () => {
    const app = shallow(<App tid={tid} />);
    const tid = app.prop('tid');
    expect(tid).toEqual('72f988bf-86f1-41af-91ab-2d7cd011db47');

});
```

Comment: Thank you. Well my goal is to check that if a user tries to access the website when login, he will be accessed only if he is trying to access with a known tenant. Also, tid is used in App.js as this.props.tid. Isn't that enough to use it over my test ?

Comment: Can you please try to edit my test such that it will work? It will be a good example for me to keep going through this. @etarhan

Comment: I'm not sure what the goal here is. You are passing property tid to App.js then use it to render your <Image /> only if it has the proper tenant ID. So checking if this element was rendered on the page as I've suggested would be good for your use case? Which element would you expect to find with `app.find('#tid')` initially?

Comment: Let's say that the user entered the website with Microsoft account. Microsoft tenant is allowed. So when he access the website,he will see the microsoft-gray.pgn image. So I should check that the app renders microsoft-gray.pgn. Is that what you mean ?

Comment: @l.zvi yes that is indeed what I mean. Since your exact condition for rendering that image is a correct tenant ID, checking for the existence of that element would be a good test. I've updated my answer with examples of what you could try.

Comment: That's a good way of thinking! I tried to use your 2nd suggestion, but it fails. I am editing my question so you can see the error